# jQueryMobile: Hide data-icon for anchor tag

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

jQueryMobile:

In a simple listview I have the following:

```
<li><a>SOME TEXT</a></li>
```

A data-icon of right arrow is displayed.

How do I have no data-icon displayed at all?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just add `data-icon="false"`, i.e.

```
<li data-icon="false"><a>SOME TEXT</a></li>
```

Comment: Took forever to find, but here's the man page with that information: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-themes.html

Comment: If you use jQuery to add this attribute, be sure to use .attr("data-icon", "false") instead of .data("icon", "false").

Comment: @JaredFarrish The link is not working anymore. It's http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/listview/ for jQM 1.4.3.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest is to remove the right class
`$("li>a").removeClass("ui-btn-icon-right");`